# the collection and values cannot show up in the Cloud Firestore in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I cannot see the collections and values in the Cloud Firestore after they were created in my Flutter app. I am working on a Flutter mobile app by using Flutter and Firebase. I use cloud firestore to keep data. when I run the app, I can see "hi" from VS Code's terminal, but when I went to the firebase, refresh the cloud firestore page, I can not see the collection and values in the cloud firestore. I tried to delete firebase project and recreate it. But it did not work. I tried to use `Collection("users").add(...).then(value){print(value.id);}`. From the terminal, I can see the ID. But I still cannot see the collection and values in the Cloud Firestore. I do not know what is wrong with my app. I need help.

The code is:

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
   import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

   void main() async {
     WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
     await Firebase.initializeApp();
     runApp(MyApp());
   }

   class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
     // This widget is the root of your application.
     override
     _createState() => _MyAppState();
   

   class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        

        // firestore: a Firestore instance
        void _onPressed() async{
           await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc().set({
            "name": "john",
            "age": 50,
        "email": "example@example.com",
        "address": {"street": "street 24", "city": "new york"}
      }).then((value) {
        print('hi');
      });
    }

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: _onPressed,
            child: Text('Click'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my build.gradle under app:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.skype_clone"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

the build.gradle under android:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

the security rule is:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

I am appreciated for any help.

Comment: do you have PERMISSION DENIED message in your console?

Comment: I do not have permission denied message. But I got status code 404 in the inspect console

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is in this declaration

```
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

I think that you should remove the **await** keyword there and in the functcion, and when you use that function to initialize Firebase in the project you need to put the credential of the project as a parameter of that function, this is an example of how you should do it:

```js
    // Initialize default app
    // Retrieve your own options values by adding a web app on
    // https://console.firebase.google.com
    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "AIza....",                             // Auth / General Use
      appId: "1:27992087142:web:ce....",              // General Use
      projectId: "my-firebase-project",               // General Use
      authDomain: "YOUR_APP.firebaseapp.com",         // Auth with popup/redirect
      databaseURL: "https://YOUR_APP.firebaseio.com", // Realtime Database
      storageBucket: "YOUR_APP.appspot.com",          // Storage
      messagingSenderId: "123456789",                 // Cloud Messaging
      measurementId: "G-12345"                        // Analytics
});
```

Please let me know if this solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

delete `await` keyword. It conflicts with `then`. You need to use or `await` or `then`:

```
void _onPressed() async{
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc().set({
        "name": "john",
        "age": 50,
        "email": "example@example.com",
        "address": {"street": "street 24", "city": "new york"}
      }).then((value) {
        print('hi');
      });
    }
```

Comment: I deleted await and async keywords. But the problem is still there.